Adjusting the negative output voltage of a bipolar step-down converter in Proteus
I'm working on designing a bipolar step-down DC-DC converter with a +12V input, targeting ±5V outputs. I'm using flying capacitors for the configuration, and I'm modeling the circuit in Proteus 8.17 SP2.
I've successfully created a circuit that produces a correct +5V output.

However, when I try to achieve the negative output, I get -10V instead of the desired -5V.

Could someone help me figure out how to adjust the circuit to achieve a stable -5V output? Here is a link to the project file https://www.dropbox.com/t/ZODFdGMa1QHWvo9c.

A buck converter uses an inductor (as implied by the word buck).

Can you give a short explanation of your circuit in your question (edit it), that is, how does it work or how do you expect it to work?
